# How to slow down a method execution without freezing the thread/application?

Tags: c++, qt, slowdown

Everything is in the title :)

Why I need this :

I've created a small playable sudoku game in C++ with Qt. I've made a classic backtracking method to resolve it. The user can see the resolution progress in real-time. I've put a slider allowing the user to adjust the resolution speed.

That's what I've put at the begging of the resolution method to slow down the process :

```
 sleep_for(milliseconds(delay)); //delay is a toggleable static variable
```

BUT since the user launch the resolution, he can't change the speed(delay) because the application is sleeping most of the time.

Any other way to slow down the process ?

ps : please excuse my rough english :/

Comment: You must use Qthread

Comment: Maybe QTimer could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use timerEvent(). QObject has timer support built in. Put each game step in the timerEvent() and call startTimer() with the required interval. This is by far the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

A Sleep is a good way to slow down an application as it free's up the processor to do other things, if you want to allow the user to change the speed you should be doing this on a seperate thread, when that time changes interupt the sleeping thread and set the new delay.

Comment: Instead of interrupting the sleeping thread, you could also just synchronize access to a shared variable. (`std::atomic` could be sufficient)

Comment: @qxz Suppose you allow a range of 0-10s for the sleep option. Then changing from 10s to 0s could take up to 10s to kick in. Interrupting is one way to resolve that (there are others).

Answer (score -2):

Well you make a loop and call the draw/write function in a set of interval

```
int interval = 0;
while(running){
    interval++;
    if(interval == 60){
        draw();
    }
}
```

or using sleep by including Windows.h

```
int fps = 1000/30;
while(running){
    Sleep(fps);
    draw();
}
```

or by combining them

```
int fps = 1000/30;
int interval = 0;
while(running){
    interval++;
    Sleep(fps);
    if(interval == 30){//every more or less 1 sec
        draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise against busy-waits, because those, use up CPU time, for absolutely **no** gain. Timing control is also bad: you don't know the exact magic constants to use, in your busy-waiter, without playing around with numbers, beforehand, and even then, you know the magic constant for just a single machine. `Sleep` sleeps for exact amount (more or less) on any machine. And, what's even _worse_ in your busy-wait examples, that the `draw` function gets called, _at most_ once.